# Can I SSH pictures directly to the iOS Camera Roll?

Tags: ipad, ios, jailbreak, ssh, camera

I want to upload a picture directly to my iPad (without syncing or downloading from email). I want to SSH into my camera roll (`/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE`), upload an image there, and be able to see it in my Photos app (Camera Roll). When I do this, the pics do not show up. I even followed Apple's naming convention (i.e `IMG_001.png`).

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!
Thomas

Answer (score 3):

Your going to have to change some sort of index file that the iPad uses to keep track of what photos are in the camera roll.  The file is probably in some sort of proprietary Apple format, the details of which are not available to the public.  You might look in to the format of the file that controls the music library, which is also not public but the details are available around the internet thanks to persistant hackers.  I bet the Photos file format is similar, with Albums swapped out for Playlists.  But I'm mostly guessing.

Good Luck!